# Websphere portal server - Accessing portal admin through the WAS console

Tags: websphere-portal

I removed my login portlet by mistake and now cannot login to view the wps admin console.  Can this be accessed through the WAS console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you just removed the portlet from the page, the easiest way to add it back to the page would be to export the login page from a different portal if available and import using xmlaccess command line.  If another portal isn't available, you could export the current portal Login page using xmlaccess command line, manually edit the xml file to add the portlet and import using xmlaccess command line.

Here is the login page export from a default portal installation:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- IBM WebSphere Portal/8.5 build 20170616-0410 exported on Sat Dec 21 10:43:08 EST 2019 from ICPortal01/172.30.15.43 virtual portal: none (default virtual portal) -->
<!-- 1 [skin ZK_00000000000000A0BR2B300670] -->
<!-- 2 [skin ZK_00000000000000A0BR2B300672] -->
<!-- 3 [skin ZK_00000000000000A0BR2B300674] -->
<!-- 4 [skin ZK_00000000000000A0BR2B300676] -->
<!-- 5 [theme ZJ_00000000000000A0BR2B300QC6] -->
<!-- 6 [content-node Z6_000000000000000000000000A0] -->
<!-- 7 [content-node Z6_00000000000000A0BR2B300G80] -->
<!-- 8 [content-node Z6_00000000000000A0BR2B300GC4] -->
<!-- 9 [component Z7_00000000000000A0BR2B300I82] -->
<!-- 10 [component Z7_00000000000000A0BR2B300I86] -->
<!-- 11 [component Z7_00000000000000A0BR2B300I81] -->
<!-- 12 [web-app Z1_00000000000000A0BR2B300IG4 uid=login.war.webmod] -->
<!-- 13 [portlet-app Z2_00000000000000A0BR2B300IG6 name=wp.ap.login uid=login.war] -->
<!-- 14 [servlet ZV_00000000000000A0BR2B300IG2] -->
<!-- 15 [portlet Z3_00000000000000A0BR2B300094 name=Login Portlet] -->
<!-- 16 [portletinstance Z5_00000000000000A0BR2B300I85] -->
<request build="20170616-0410" type="update" version="8.5.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="PortalConfig_8.5.0.xsd">
    <portal action="locate">
        <skin action="locate" domain="rel" objectid="ZK_00000000000000A0BR2B300670" uniquename="ibm.portal.85Hidden"/>
        <skin action="locate" domain="rel" objectid="ZK_00000000000000A0BR2B300672" uniquename="ibm.portal.85Standard"/>
        <skin action="locate" domain="rel" objectid="ZK_00000000000000A0BR2B300674" uniquename="ibm.portal.85HiddenPlus"/>
        <skin action="locate" domain="rel" objectid="ZK_00000000000000A0BR2B300676" uniquename="ibm.portal.85NoSkin"/>
        <theme action="locate" domain="rel" objectid="ZJ_00000000000000A0BR2B300QC6" uniquename="ibm.portal.85Theme"/>
        <web-app action="locate" domain="rel" objectid="Z1_00000000000000A0BR2B300IG4" uid="login.war.webmod">
            <servlet action="locate" domain="rel" name="Login Portlet" objectid="ZV_00000000000000A0BR2B300IG2"/>
            <portlet-app action="locate" domain="rel" name="wp.ap.login" objectid="Z2_00000000000000A0BR2B300IG6" uid="login.war">
                <portlet action="locate" domain="rel" name="Login Portlet" objectid="Z3_00000000000000A0BR2B300094" uniquename="wps.p.Login"/>
            </portlet-app>
        </web-app>
        <content-node action="locate" domain="rel" objectid="Z6_000000000000000000000000A0" uniquename="wps.content.root"/>
        <content-node action="locate" domain="rel" objectid="Z6_00000000000000A0BR2B300G80" uniquename="ibm.portal.HiddenPages"/>
        <content-node action="update" active="true" allportletsallowed="true" content-parentref="Z6_00000000000000A0BR2B300G80" create-type="explicit" domain="rel" objectid="Z6_00000000000000A0BR2B300GC4" ordinal="10" themeref="undefined" type="page" uniquename="wps.Login">
            <supported-markup markup="html" update="set"/>
            <localedata locale="ar">
                <title>بدء الاتصال</title>
            </localedata>
            <localedata locale="ca">
                <title>Inici de sessió</title>
            </localedata>
            <localedata locale="cs">
                <title>Přihlášení</title>
            </localedata>
            <localedata locale="da">
                <title>Logon</title>
            </localedata>
            <localedata locale="de">
                <title>Anmeldung</title>
            </localedata>
            <localedata locale="el">
                <title>Σύνδεση</title>
            </localedata>
            <localedata locale="en">
                <title>Login</title>
            </localedata>
            <localedata locale="es">
                <title>Inicio de sesión</title>
            </localedata>
            <localedata locale="fi">
                <title>Kirjaudu sisään</title>
            </localedata>
            <localedata locale="fr">
                <title>Connexion</title>
            </localedata>
            <localedata locale="hu">
                <title>Bejelentkezés</title>
            </localedata>
            <localedata locale="it">
                <title>Login</title>
            </localedata>
            <localedata locale="iw">
                <title>התחברות</title>
            </localedata>
            <localedata locale="ja">
                <title>ログイン</title>
            </localedata>
            <localedata locale="ko">
                <title>로그인</title>
            </localedata>
            <localedata locale="nl">
                <title>Aanmelden</title>
            </localedata>
            <localedata locale="no">
                <title>Logg på</title>
            </localedata>
            <localedata locale="pl">
                <title>Logowanie</title>
            </localedata>
            <localedata locale="pt">
                <title>Iniciar sessão</title>
            </localedata>
            <localedata locale="pt_BR">
                <title>Efetuar Login</title>
            </localedata>
            <localedata locale="ro">
                <title>Logare</title>
            </localedata>
            <localedata locale="ru">
                <title>Вход в систему</title>
            </localedata>
            <localedata locale="sk">
                <title>Prihlásiť</title>
            </localedata>
            <localedata locale="sl">
                <title>Prijava</title>
            </localedata>
            <localedata locale="sv">
                <title>Inloggning</title>
            </localedata>
            <localedata locale="th">
                <title>ลงชื่อเข้าใช้</title>
            </localedata>
            <localedata locale="tr">
                <title>Oturum Aç</title>
            </localedata>
            <localedata locale="uk">
                <title>Вхід до системи</title>
            </localedata>
            <localedata locale="zh">
                <title>登录</title>
            </localedata>
            <localedata locale="zh_TW">
                <title>登入</title>
            </localedata>
            <localedata locale="hr">
                <title>Prijava:</title>
            </localedata>
            <localedata locale="kk">
                <title>Кіру</title>
            </localedata>
            <parameter name="RenderMode" type="string" update="set"><![CDATA[force_ssa]]></parameter>
            <parameter name="com.ibm.portal.Hidden" type="string" update="set"><![CDATA[true]]></parameter>
            <parameter name="com.ibm.portal.PageIcon" type="string" update="set"><![CDATA[icons/page/login.gif]]></parameter>
            <parameter name="com.ibm.portal.ThemePolicy" type="string" update="set"><![CDATA[theme/NoTheme]]></parameter>
            <parameter name="param.sharing.scope.{http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/datatype/content/resource-collections}" type="string" update="set"><![CDATA[ibm.portal.sharing.scope.page]]></parameter>
            <parameter name="param.sharing.scope.{http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/datatype/content}" type="string" update="set"><![CDATA[ibm.portal.sharing.scope.page]]></parameter>
            <parameter name="param.sharing.scope.{http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/websphere/portal/publicparams}path-info" type="string" update="set"><![CDATA[ibm.portal.sharing.scope.page]]></parameter>
            <parameter name="resourceaggregation.profile" type="string" update="set"><![CDATA[profiles/profile_deferred.json]]></parameter>
            <access-control externalized="false" owner="undefined" private="false">
                <role actionset="User" update="set">
                    <mapping subjectid="anonymous portal user" subjecttype="user" update="set"/>
                    <mapping subjectid="all authenticated portal users" subjecttype="user_group" update="set"/>
                </role>
            </access-control>
            <content-mapping-info>
                <content-mapping content-id="gxsywmg-dxsywmgvtkqzcustgoailgykonin" default="false" delegated-access-level="User" system="true"/>
            </content-mapping-info>
            <component action="update" active="true" deletable="undefined" domain="rel" modifiable="undefined" objectid="Z7_00000000000000A0BR2B300I82" ordinal="100" orientation="H" skinref="undefined" type="container" width="undefined">
                <component action="update" active="true" deletable="undefined" domain="rel" modifiable="undefined" objectid="Z7_00000000000000A0BR2B300I86" ordinal="99" orientation="V" skinref="undefined" type="container" width="700">
                    <component action="update" active="true" deletable="undefined" domain="rel" modifiable="undefined" objectid="Z7_00000000000000A0BR2B300I81" ordinal="99" skinref="undefined" type="control" width="undefined">
                        <portletinstance action="update" domain="rel" objectid="Z5_00000000000000A0BR2B300I85" portletref="Z3_00000000000000A0BR2B300094"/>
                    </component>
                </component>
            </component>
        </content-node>
    </portal>
    <status element="all" result="ok"/>
</request>
```

You can use command similar to the below to import:

```
xmlaccess.bat -user PORTALADMINUSER -pwd PORTALADMINPWD -url http://localhost:10040/wps/config -in path_to_import_file.xml
```

Another solution would be to login to a Virtual portal if you have one available on that same portal and then switch the url to the base portal.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

One easy solution is login with query parameter as per below:

```
http://server:port/wps/portal/cxml/04_SD9ePMtCP1I800I_KydQvyHFUBADPmuQy?userid=userid&password=password
```

Example:

```
http://myportalserver.example.com:10039/wps/portal/cxml/04_SD9ePMtCP1I800I_KydQvyHFUBADPmuQy?userid=wpsadmin&password=wpsadmin
```

Further you can just map the portlet again to page from Administration.
Hope this will help you.